# Grouping controls together on an Access form Enable

Tags: ms-access, vba

How could I shorten this code? I already put their tag name as Group_Sal1?

```
    Public Function Salary_Text_Editable()
    Me.BasicSal.Enabled = True
    Me.HouseAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.TransAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.PetrolAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.AirfareAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.MobileAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.COLA.Enabled = True
    Me.OtherAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.SiteAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.RemoteAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.FoodAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.EWOT.Enabled = True
    Me.SaudiAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.QatarAllow.Enabled = True
    Me.BaynunahAllow.Enabled = True
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the form's `Controls` collection and examine the `Tag` property of each.  Enable the control if its tag matches *"Group_Sal1"*.

```vb
Public Function Salary_Text_Editable()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Group_Sal1" Then
            ctl.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. but unfortunately i still have a debug. i don't know why?